# Why is leftMargin adding half its amount to the top and bottom?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-constraintlayout, breadcrumbs

My Layout seems to be adding an extra 1/2 margin at the top and bottom of the adjacent sides to it. Is this just what margin does? Is there a way to redefine the margins so that it only adjusts the left side or right side? I could also be using the wrong parameter.

Below is a picture of what is wrong.

I want the the vMargin around the entire image.

```
    public Part2View(Context context, List<ImageView> images, int vMargin) {
        super(context);

        ConstraintLayout container = new ConstraintLayout(context); // create the parent container for the images
        addView(container);                         // add it to Part2View
        container.setId(0);                         // set its ID to 0. This lets us refer to it later


        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            ImageView img = images.get(i);    // The image
            //img.setId(i+1);
            // TODO: Make sure the image scales properly
            img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            //other stuff
            // TODO: Add the image to the interactor hierarchy
            container.addView(img);
            // TODO: Set the image ID so you can refer to it later
            img.setId(i+1);
            // TODO: Create some ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams and set them so the image will expand in X and minimize Y
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
            params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.leftToLeft = 0;
            params.rightToRight = 0;
            if(i == 0) {
                params.topToTop = 0;
            } else {
                params.topToBottom = i;
            }
            params.rightMargin = vMargin;
            if(i < images.size() - 1) {
//
//                params.bottomMargin = vMargin;
            }
            img.setLayoutParams(params);

            // TODO: Set the parameters to use the constraint layout so that the image looks like it did in Part1

        }
    }
```

[image: Image of margin]

Comment: Add appropriate tags for the platform, GUI toolkit you are using. Java is too vague.

Comment: You're using Android Studio right? Instead of coding the activity, create one which will then be an xml file

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do this in java for an assignment. I also am curious why this is the case.